# Generic Class with Enum with associated values

Tags: ios, swift, generics, enums, associated-value

I'm trying to create a generic `UITableViewCell` that inherits from an enum with associated values.
This is what I tried:

Enum declaration:

```
enum Content: Equatable  {
    case text(String)
    case image(UIImage)
    case error(Error)
    case indicator
}
```

And `UITableViewCell` declaration:

```
class MessageTableViewCell<T: Content>: UITableViewCell {
    var content: T?
}
```

But it fails with:

```
Type 'T' constrained to non-protocol, non-class type 'Content'
```

I'm trying to set up my cell with different types of "content view," depending on its content. Do note: I'm using XIB for the interface of the cell, so subclassing is not possible (I think). Any advice will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Can you clarify why you are trying to use generics versus just defining the `content` property with a type of `Content`?

Comment: @HangarRash I thought about it as well, good point!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the error, you need to constrain it to either a protocol or a class. You can try the below code.

```
enum Content  {
    case text(String)
    case image(UIImage)
    case error(Error)
    case indicator
}

protocol CellContent {
    var content: Content { get set }
}

class MessageTableViewCell<T: CellContent>: UITableViewCell {
    var content: T?
}
```